# aws-embedded-metrics-java dimension usage and resetting

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function that reads in and processes a collection of purchase entries from S3. Each purchase has the following fields:

1. country
2. store
3. language

I want to emit metrics about this data into cloud watch and I'm using [aws-embedded-metrics-java](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-embedded-metrics-java). In cloudwatch I want to be able to see things like total purchases, average purchases in X country, purchases by locale, ...etc... etc.... However, when I emit the metrics like this:

```
MetricsLogger metricsLogger =  new MetricsLogger();
for (Purchase purchase : purhcaseCollection) {

                DimensionSet dimensionSet = DimensionSet.of(
                        "country", purchase.getCountry(),
                        "store", purchase.getStore(),
                        "language", purchase.getLanguage()
                );
                metricsLogger.putMetric(
                        "purchase",
                        1,
                        dimensionSet
                );
                
}
```

I am only able to see one country, store, and language combination in cloudwatch when I expected to see many more. I think its because I am not resetting the metrics dimensions and all purchases are being associated with last dimension set I specify. Do I need to call

```
 metricsLogger.resetDimensions(false);
```

each time I use a dimension set? That would also mean that if I emit any metrics before iterating over the purchase collection i.e. if there is some exception before this I want to log a count for I'll also need to reset the dimensions?